# Is it safe to override GetHashCode and get it from string property?

Tags: c#, .net, gethashcode

I have a class:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

The purpose of overriding GetHashCode is that I want to have only one occurence of an object with specified name in Dictionary.

But is it safe to get hash code from string?
In other words, is there any chance that two objects with different values of property Name would return the same hash code?

Comment: Hash codes are *not* guaranteed to be unique. Consider that it returns an `int`, but there are far more than 2^32 possible strings.

Comment: You **must must must** ***only ever*** compute the hash code from **immutable values** - otherwise your object won't work correctly in any dictionary or hash table.

Answer (score 4):

> But is it safe to get hash code from string?

Yes, it is safe. **But**, what you're doing isn't. You're using a mutable `string` field to generate your hash code. Let's imagine that you inserted an `Item` as a key for a given value. Then, someone changes the `Name` string to something else. You now are no longer able to find the same `Item` inside your `Dictionary`, `HashSet`, or whichever structure you use.

More-so, you should be relying on immutable types only. I'd also advise you to implement `IEquatable<T>` as well:

```
public class Item : IEquatable<Item>
{
    public Item(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    public bool Equals(Item other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return string.Equals(Name, other.Name);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((Item) obj);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Item left, Item right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Item left, Item right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (Name != null ? Name.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }
}
```

> is there any chance that two objects with different values of property
>   Name would return the same hash code?

Yes, there is a statistical chance that such a thing will happen. Hash codes do not guarantee uniqueness. They strive for uni-formal distribution. Why? because your upper boundary is `Int32`, which is 32bits. Given the [Pigenhole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), you may happen at end up with two different strings containing the same hash code.

Comment: You may happen to end up with the same hash code if you generate two strings. If you're unlucky. The number of strings you're working with changes the probability of it happening, not the possibility.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You're right. Is there anything in my answer that conveys otherwise?

Comment: You've already made the edit to the sentence that was most suggestive.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Good then :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your class is buggy, because you have a `GetHashCode` override, but no `Equals` override. You also don't consider the case where `Name` is null.

The rule for `GetHashCode` is simple:

If `a.Equals(b)` then it must be the case that `a.GetHashCode() == b.GetHashCode()`.

The more cases where if `!a.Equals(b)` then `a.GetHashCode() != b.GetHashCode()` the better, indeed the more cases where `!a.Equals(b)` then `a.GetHashCode() % SomeValue != b.GetHashCode() % SomeValue` the better, for any given `SomeValue` (you can't predict it) so we like to have a good mix of bits in the results. But the **vital** thing is that two objects considered equal **must** have equal `GetHashCode()` results.

Right now this isn't the case, because you've only overridden one of these. However the following is sensible:

```
public class Item
{
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
      return Name == null ? 0 : Name.GetHashCode();
  }
  public override bool Equals(object obj)
  {
    var asItem = obj as Item;
    return asItem != null && Name == obj.Name;
  }
}
```

The following is even better, because it allows for faster strongly-typed equality comparisons:

```
public class Item : IEquatable<Item>
{
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
      return Name == null ? 0 : Name.GetHashCode();
  }
  public bool Equals(Item other)
  {
    return other != null && Name == other.Name;
  }
  public override bool Equals(object obj)
  {
    return Equals(obj as Item);
  }
}
```

> In other words, is there any chance that two objects with different values of property Name would return the same hash code?

Yes, this can happen, but it won't happen often, so that's fine. The hash-based collections like `Dictionary` and `HashSet` can handle a few collisions; indeed there'll be collisions even if the hash codes are all different because they're modulo'd down to a smaller index. It's only if this happens a lot that it impacts performance.

Another danger is that you'll be using a mutable value as a key. There's a myth that you shouldn't use mutable values for hash-codes, which isn't true; if a mutable object has a mutable property that affects what it is considered equal with then it **must** result in a change to the hash-code.

The real danger is mutating an object that is a key to a hash collection at all. If you are defining equality based on `Name` and you have such an object as the key to a dictionary then you **must not** change `Name` while it is used as such a key. The easiest way to ensure that is to have `Name` be immutable, so that is definitely a good idea if possible. If it is not possible though, you need to be careful just when you allow `Name` to be changed.

From a comment:

> So, even if there is a collision in hash codes, when Equals will return false (because the names are different), the Dictionary will handle propertly?

Yes, it will handle it, though it's not ideal. We can test this with a class like this:

```
public class SuckyHashCode : IEquatable<SuckyHashCode>
{
  public int Value { get; set; }
  public bool Equals(SuckyHashCode other)
  {
    return other != null && other.Value == Value;
  }
  public override bool Equals(object obj)
  {
    return Equals(obj as SuckyHashCode);
  }
  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Now if we use this, it works:

```
var dict = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(i => new SuckyHashCode{Value = i}).ToDictionary(shc => shc);
Console.WriteLine(dict.ContainsKey(new SuckyHashCode{Value = 3})); // True
Console.WriteLine(dict.ContainsKey(new SuckyHashCode{Value = -1})); // False
```

However, as the name suggests, it isn't ideal. Dictionaries and other hash-based collections all have means to deal with collisions, but those means mean that we no longer have the great nearly O(1) look-up, but rather as the percentage of collisions gets greater the look-up approaches O(n). In the case above where the `GetHashCode` is as bad as it could be without actually throwing an exception, the look-up would be O(n) which is the same as just putting all the items into an unordered collection and then finding them by looking at every one to see if it matches (indeed, due to differences in overheads, it's actually worse than that).

So for this reason we always want to avoid collisions as much as possible. Indeed, to not just avoid collisions, but to avoid collisions after the result has been modulo'd down to make a smaller hash code (because that's what happens internally to the dictionary).

In your case though because `string.GetHashCode()` is reasonably good at avoiding collisions, and because that one string is the only thing that equality is defined by, your code would in turn be reasonably good at avoiding collisions. More collision-resistant code is certainly possible, but comes at a cost to performance in the the code itself* and/or is more work than can be justified.

*(Though see https://www.nuget.org/packages/SpookilySharp/ for code of mine that is faster than `string.GetHashCode()` on large strings on 64-bit .NET and more collision-resistant, though it is slower to produce those hash codes on 32-bit .NET or when the string is short).

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention it, as I didn't realize that it's important, but yes, I'm implementing IEquatable<Item> interface and I'm overriding the Equals(Item other) method as well. So, even if there is a collision in hash codes, when Equals will return false (because the names are different), the Dictionary will handle propertly?

Comment: @Szybki yes. I'll add a bit on that to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the great answear. But there's another problem I didn't even know about. It's about the mutable property used as a key. While others state that I shouldn't use mutable string as a key, you say that it's a myth, so it confuse me a little bit. I don't really understand the danger of the key's mutability, as I'm aware of user renaming the object to a name that already exist in dictionary.

Comment: It's a myth based on a real danger; If you're using something as a key, and then change that key so that it's no longer equal to what it was when it was used as a key, how is it supposed to be found?

Comment: Imagine for analogy if you had records about people in an alphabetical filing cabinet, that somehow magically changed if the person they were about changed their names. You have "Miss Alice Smith" filed under "S". She changes her name to "Mrs Alice Jones". Now if you can't find her either way; if you look up "Mrs Alice Jones" you don't find her (she's filed under "S", and you look under "J") and if you try to find "Miss Alice Smith" you don't find her (there's no such record under "S" any more). Keys don't have to be totally immutable, but they do have to not mutate **while used as keys**.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `GetHashCode` to prevent duplicates to be added to a dictionary, which is risky in your case as explained already, I would recommend to use a (custom) [equality comparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) for your dictionary.

If the key is an object, you should create an own equality comparer that compares the `string Name` value. If the key is the `string` itself, you can use [`StringComparer.CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer(v=vs.110).aspx) for example.

Also in this case it is key to make the `string` immutable, since else you might invalidate your dictionary by changing the `Name`.